# Extending streambuf

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm implementing an object oriented socket interface in C++, using POSIX sockets and file descriptors.
My problem is that when I read bytes from the `istream` (which I subclassed to `fdistream`), it doesn't return data until I disconnect the socket.

What is it waiting for? Is it waiting for a line feed even if I'm treating it as a binary stream?
I need to get the byte as soon as the client sends it. (Trying with Java works).

`underflow()` implementation:

```
fdinbuf::int_type fdinbuf::underflow () {

    if (gptr() < egptr()) {
        return traits_type::to_int_type(*gptr());
    }

    int numPutback;
    numPutback = (int)(gptr() - eback());
    if (numPutback > pbSize) {
        numPutback = pbSize;
    }

    memmove(buffer+(pbSize-numPutback), gptr()-numPutback, numPutback);

    int num;
    num = (int)read (fd, buffer+pbSize, bufSize);
    if (num <= 0) {
        return EOF;
    }

    setg (buffer+(pbSize-numPutback),
          buffer+pbSize,
          buffer+pbSize+num);

    return traits_type::to_int_type(*gptr());
}
```

Comment: Have you seen boost iostreams?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to understand the logic of c++ streams. What makes the stream returns the data to the upper layer?

Comment: That's fine, just a sanity check.

Comment: "*My problem is that when I read bytes from the istream, it doesn't return data until I disconnect the socket*" - hard to diagnose that since you did not show the code that is reading from the `istream`, or what the socket data looks like, so we can't tell you what the reading code is waiting on. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).